# How does the Astral Skin of the Astral Suit work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, psionics

The [Aegis](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis) have an [Astral Suit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/astral-suits), which comes in 3 flavors: The Astral Skin, Astral Armor, and Astral Juggernaut. One line in the description on the Astral Skin entry reads:

> An astral suit in this form does not count as any type of armor, but does count as a psychoactive skin and follows all the rules of a psychoactive skin.

There are many different [Psychoactive Skins](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/universal-items#TOC-Psychoactive-Skins), and they have different abilities, and cost is based on the abilities. Skins range from Skin of the Claw which costs 16,000 gp, to Skin of the Psion which costs 151,000 gp.

The Aegis gains the Astral Suit at Level 1. Does this mean a Level 1 Aegis can manifest his suit as an Astral Skin with the same abilities as an item that costs 151,000 gp, or does it only mean to act in the following way, with no extra abilities?

> A deployed skin completely covers the wearer and all his equipment like a second skin, allowing the wearer to see, hear, and breathe normally. It rolls away from various parts of the body as needed, such as when the wearer needs to eat or access a backpack. Held items or items specifically excluded are not covered by a psychoactive skin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The astral skin operates according to the general rules of psychoactive skins, not according to the rules of any particular psychoactive skin. So yes, your second quote applies, and no, the benefits of a 151,000-gp item (or 16,000-gp item) don’t.

It is effectively the “unarmored” version of the astral suit; the astral skin can actually be combined with regular armor. When the rules for psychoactive skins says

> Each of the various psychoactive skins is charged with one of a wide array of powers that constantly affect the wearer.

In the case of the astral skin, that means the astral suit customizations (including the default free *speed* (2) and *nimble*).